# array_diff does not work PHP

Tags: php

```
Array 1 ($allmodels)
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 7 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [id] => 8 ) ) 

Array 2 ($existmodels)
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [id] => 7 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [id] => 5 ) )
```

What I want as output array is(get the remaining models using $allmodels - $existmodels )

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 8 ))
```

I tried

`array_diff($allmodels,$existmodels);` AND `array_diff_assoc($allmodels,$existmodels);` which both result

> Array ( )

Can anyone tell me how can I get it done ?

Comment: Try switching the order of the arrays? $existmodels first.

Comment: have to do it this way. all models gonna be larger array when my db grows up

Comment: @JonStirling That's not the problem. The problem is `array_diff()` converts the elements into strings for comparison. Because the OP has multidimensional arrays, every element converts to `Array` and the function will return an empty array no matter what.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I exactly want. I want only Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 8 )) as the output

Comment: Sorry, my bad, wrong end of the stick. So the issue is that you're trying to get a diff on a multi-dimensional array. Will do more thinking...

Comment: OP, `array_diff()` won't work here, at least not with the arrays structured as they are. If you're pulling this from a SQL database, you should really compute the difference there. You always want to pull as little information from the database as possible.

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026431/php-mutidimensional-array-diff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note of array_diff:**

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 ===
>   (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.

The string representation of array is both `Array`, so this is the reason why you get empty array as result.

You could use [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) instead.

```
var_dump(array_filter($allmodels, function ($var) use ($existmodels) {
  return !in_array($var, $existmodels);
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_diff` does not work on multi-dimensional arrays. You have to either unwrap and re-wrap your ids:

```
$diff = array_map(function ($i) { return array('id' => $i); },
                  array_diff(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id']; }, $array1),
                             array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id']; }, $array2)));
```

or set them as keys, which are easily diffed:

```
$diff = array_diff_key(array_combine(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id']; }, $array1), $array1),
                       array_combine(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id']; }, $array2), $array2));
```

Comment: returns Warning: array_combine() [<a href='function.array-combine'>function.array-combine</a>]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$array1 = array( 0 =>array('id'=>1), 1=> array('id'=>2));
$array2 = array( 0 =>array('id'=>3), 1=> array('id'=>2));
$diff = array();

foreach($array1 as $value1)
{

  foreach($array2 as $value2)
  {
    if($value1['id'] == $value2['id'])
    continue 2;
  }

  $diff[] = $value1;
}
echo nl2br(print_r($diff,1));
```

Comment: I learned nl2br function here for the 1st time. By the way thanks for the code snippet